# PG error using rails where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I have simple query like

```
User.where('(zone_id IN (?) AND zone_type = "Org") OR (zone_id = ? AND zone_type ="Com")', [1,2,3], 10)
```

This throws me

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "Org" does not exist
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure try this `User.where('(zone_id IN (?),zone_type = "Org") OR (zone_id = ?,zone_type ="Com")', [1,2,3], 10)`

Comment: `User.where('(zone_id IN (?),zone_type = ?) OR (zone_id = ?,zone_type =?)', [1,2,3], "org", 10, "com")` Try use this

Comment: I don't think comas are valid to be used in "query" in `where`, check - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions

Comment: Could you try: `User.where("(zone_id IN (:zone_ids) AND zone_type = :org_zone) OR (zone_id = :another_zone AND zone_type = :om_zone)", { zone_ids: [123], org_zone: "Org", another_zone: 10, com_zone: "Com" })`?

Comment: `User.where(zone_id: [1,3,5] AND zone_type:"org").or.where(zone_id: 10 AND zone_type: "com")`

Comment: @PawełDawczak, your suggestion was correct. I've replaced strings with ? and that worked. Thanks. Add this to answer and i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently replacing all conditions fixes the problem:

```
User.where('(zone_id IN (?) AND zone_type = "?") OR (zone_id = ? AND zone_type ="?")', [1,2,3], "Org", 10, "Com")
```

I would suggest following solition, which is more readable:

```
User.where(zone_id: [1,3,5] AND zone_type:"org").or.where(zone_id: 10 AND zone_type: "com")
```

Answer (score 1):

More Rails way,
You don't have to use `IN` operator

```
User.where(zone_id: [1,3,5] AND zone_type:"org").or.where(zone_id: 10 AND zone_type: "com")
```